# How to increment or decrement my price when you do +1% or -10% in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, math, percentage

I want to increment my price by  the percentage that the user types in the UI, how do I do the math of that?

for example with simple math you do it like this

1. Increase the value by 1%:  `1.45 x 1.01 = 1.4645`
2. Decrease the value by 1%:  `1.45 x 0.99 = 1.4355`
3. Increase the value by 10%:  `1.45 x 1.10 = 1.595`
4. Decrease the value by 1%:  `1.45 x 0.90 = 1.305`

But I don’t know how to do it with flutter because the user is gonna put a value from 1 to 1000 in the percentage that he wants to add.

How to change that value to match the equation above?

Comment: What's the actual question? What does a sample input look like?

Comment: My question is in the title and in the body I explained what I got so far and that I'm interested in only  the math side of the solution not the UI part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is the percentage the user fills in the UI and y is the value, then you do:

```
(x / 100 + 1) × y
```

x is positive for increase and negative for decreasing percentage.

Comment: but where does the 1 come from though , why is it needed?, can you  explain pls

Comment: Yeap that solves my problem, thxn :D

Comment: The division multiplied with the original value calculates the difference that will be added or subtracted. The 1 is needed since you want the total new value, not just the difference.  It could also be written as `x × y / 100 + y` if that floats your boat :)

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will solve the problem. Just writing an answer to show you by codes.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double originalPrice = 50;
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
int defaultPercentage = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
         controller: textController,
          onChanged:(val){
            setState((){});
          }
        ),
        Text("Original Price : $originalPrice"),
        Text("Price in % ${originalPrice+(originalPrice*(int.tryParse(textController.text)?? defaultPercentage)/100)})")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```